# joining two tables

Tags: sql

I have users table. There are three other tables: developers, managers, testers. All of these tables have a foreign key user_id.

I need to find all the users who are either developer or manager. What the sql will look like?

Update: Someone can be both a developer and a manager.

Comment: Have you considered that your data may be over-normalized?

Comment: What do you expect as output when someone is a developer, a manager or both? Just the user_id? His function in one record? Two records?

Comment: @Lieven Just the user_id

Comment: that's so odd...whenever i run one of the queries I believe to be correct, my computer either segfaults or gives me kernel panic...perhaps this problem and its solution fundamentally disturbs the very nature of the physical framework which is the very fabric of logic and computer science.

Comment: @Roland: I think this query maps directly to the MySQL engine of the Matrix, not to the user-level emulation that runs our MySQL engines. They probably didn't remove it of their query cache.

Comment: @Quassnoi: so what pill did you take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it would be

```
SELECT  u.*, 'Developer'
FROM    users u
        INNER JOIN developer d ON d.user_id = u.user_id
UNION ALL 
SELECT  u.*, 'Manager'
FROM    users u
        INNER JOIN manager m ON m.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users u
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    developers
        WHERE   user_id = u.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    managers
        WHERE   user_id = u.id
        )
```

Comment: Quassnoi - good! but you have a typo - users needs a u alias.

Comment: @Roland: we really need an embedded query parser on SO!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    u.*, 
          CASE d.user_id IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END is_developer,
          CASE m.user_id IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END is_manager
FROM      users u                -- all users
LEFT JOIN developers d           -- perhaps a developer
ON        u.user_id = d.user_id
LEFT JOIN manager m              -- perhaps a manager
ON        u.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE     d.user_id IS NOT NULL  -- either a developer
   OR     m.user_id IS NOT NULL  -- or a manager (or both)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    user_id
     /* ...other desired columns from the user table... */
FROM
    user
WHERE
    user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM developer UNION SELECT user_id FROM manager)
```

Here I am using IN rather than EXISTS so that the developer and manager tables only need to be queried one time. It's possible that the optimizer may do this anyway, but this makes it explicit.

Also, this solution does not return duplicates for users who are both managers and developers.

Comment: I'd use UNION ALL in this case...you are now unnecessarily de-deduplicating the subquery result due to UNION

Comment: @Roland: the engines will take care of it automatically. Even `MySQL` is smart enough to ignore `DISTINCT` in the `IN` predicate.

Comment: @Roland Bouman - I was wondering where all this reflexive UNION ALL was coming from. So it's a performance thing. I don't think I'm going to switch, because the UNION statement is the one place in all of the SQL language where the functionality actually matches Relational Database Theory!

Comment: @Jeffrey: I think what Quassnoi means is that in your solution, it doesn't make a difference. The other solutions do benefit from a union all performance wise.

Comment: @Quassnoi: thanks, didn't know that. That said, my SQL is habitual. If I don't need UNION, it's gonna be UNION ALL forevah evah :)

Comment: @Roland: if you look into my answer, you'll see the same :) I just wanted to say it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I know this isn't a popular opinion, but SELECT's ability to return duplicate rows is a bug (one of many) in the design of SQL. UNION's default behavior gets it right. UNION ALL is a way to tell SQL to just "do it wrong, as usual". Whether the query decides that dupe elimination is necessary, because of what it knows about the unique constraints on the source tables or the queries themselves, and how it eliminates dupes--existing indexes, implicitly building indexes, or doing table-scans, etc.--are irrelivant implementation details. Describing what you want, not how to get it, is the goal.

Comment: Jeffrey, I don't think you can generically say that implementation details are irrelevant. They are not when you suffer from them.

Comment: @Jeffrey: It is often said that SQL is set-based, but strictly speaking, it's not. SQL was designed to be able to work with multisets (bags), not only with sets. Limiting it to only set operations would complicate many real-world tasks.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Yes, with SQL we can get a list of all the things that Steve Martin needs: this lamp, and this tennis racket, and this lamp, and this ash tray, and this lamp, and this tennis racket, and this ash tray, and this lamp...  :-P